# Auto-Restart for Spring Boot Tests

Tags: spring-boot, maven, testing

I am currently writing unit and integration tests for a Spring Boot application. I'm using Spring Tool Suites 4 for development.

When I run the application using Spring Tool Suites, the auto-restart works fine when I modify and save a file. I'm trying to find a similar way to run my tests.

I currently run the tests using a separate Windows CMD terminal using Maven:

```
mvn test
```

This runs one time and terminates. Is there anyway to have the tests run every time a test file is saved?

Edit: Here's an example of a test I am running that uses JUnit and Spring to run the tests. This is taken straight from the Spring.io website https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
public class ControllerTest {

  @Autowired
  private Controller controller;

  @Test
  public void contexLoads() throws Exception {
    assertThat(controller).isNotNull();
  }
}
```

Comment: You are correct I am using JUnit but it also requires a Spring Boot context for the tests to run. I've added an example of one my tests to show it's dependency on Spring Boot.

Comment: @MarkB He is using JUnit Jupiter and not JUnit 4. You can run the tests from your IDE? Or do you search for a plugin which automatically starts your tests?

Comment: I am able to run tests using JUnit in the IDE. I downloaded the Infinitest extension and it is close to what I am looking for although I don't like how it displays the logs and output. I was looking for something I could run in a separate terminal.

Comment: I used infinitest a long time ago...but it does not really help..I ran manually via keyboard the tests I need (switched to IDEA intelliJ makes it easier...)...

Answer (score 1):

I found this Maven plugin https://github.com/fizzed/maven-plugins#watcher-fizzed-watcher-maven-plugin that will watch files and let you run specific Maven goals on file changes.

I added the plugin to my POM and changed the goal to "test".

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.fizzed</groupId>
      <artifactId>fizzed-watcher-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.6</version>
      <configuration>
        <touchFile>target/classes/watcher.txt</touchFile>
        <watches>
          <watch>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
          </watch>
          <watch>
            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
          </watch>
        </watches>
        <goals>
          <goal>test</goal> 
        </goals>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  <plugins>
<build>
```

I opened a terminal within Spring Tool Suites (ctrl + alt + t) and docked it next to my console and ran the following:

```
mvn fizzed-watcher:run
```

So far this seems to be working exactly like I want.

Comment: Are there other goals like `run` as well? I want to use the same watcher in my project but want the project to (build and) reload once detected changes